# creating text view programmatically(not in xml)

Tags: android

I want to create more then one TextView based on the condition of a for loop.
how to do it  programmatically?

Template :

```
app name: facebook

duration: 2 

app name: messaging

duration: 4

app name: temple run

duration: 2
```

Comment: Which condition want to apply to which and how??

Answer (score 0):

You can just [create a TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#TextView%28android.content.Context%29) like this:

```
TextView myTextView = new TextView(this);
myTextView.setText("A TextView");
```

then you can add this view to your layout

Answer (score 0):

Add an `id` field in layout in xml. Take reference of layout in your class.     Create views and add it to layout.

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById (R.id.YourID);        
TextView textView = new TextView (this);     
textView. setText ("YourText");     
linearLayout. addView (textView);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to create text view programmaticaly:

```
TextView mTextView = new TextView(this);
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
mTextView.setLayoutParams(params);

rootView.addView(mTextView, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understoond:

You have two array 1.appname 2. duration then try following code.

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.YourID);
    for (int i = 0; i < appname.length; i++) 
    {
        TextView textAppname = new TextView(this);
        TextView textDuration = new TextView(this);
        LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        textAppname.setLayoutParams(params);
        textDuration.setLayoutParams(params);

        textAppname.setText(appname[i]);
        textDuration.setText(duration[i]);
        linearLayout.addView(textAppname);
        linearLayout.addView(textDuration);
    }
```